# Until you cry to stop or until you cry to make me stop?

Tags: grammar

I wanna share jokes to my friends to make them laugh hard till they cry & beg to stop. Which sentence would be correct to tell them?

1. I wanna tell you jokes and make you laugh until *you cry to stop it*.
2. I wanna tell you jokes and make you laugh until *you cry to make me stop it*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ["cry" has two meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cry):

> to utter loudly : SHOUT
>
> to shed tears often noisily : WEEP, SOB

If I *cry to stop* it, I loudly tell you to stop it. So if your intended reaction is to have your friends say "Stop it!", then you'd use the first sentence.

If you want to make your friends cry (as in, have tears fall from their eyes) in an attempt to make you feel sorry, which will in turn cause you to stop telling jokes, you'd use the second sentence. (Note that this usually is not the intended reaction to a joke).

You could also use the second sentence if you want your friends to shout *at someone* to make them stop you. For example, if you're telling jokes at a bar and want your friends to shout "Make him/her stop it!" at the bartender. (This usually doesn't make for a good comedy evening, either).